# Can we kill [bad-moderation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [bad-moderation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-moderation) sounds vague and judgemental.  What exactly about what happened is "bad"?  Shouldn't a tag for *that* be used instead (like [bias](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias), in use on at least one of these questions)?  In any difference of opinion between an unhappy user and a moderator, one side of that is going to want to apply the word "bad"; that doesn't make it so.

What does this tag add?  If the answer is "nothing", what should we do with the questions so tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just taken care of all questions [bad-moderation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-moderation).

We're left with three questions that relate to *incorrect actions taken by a moderator*, one of which also held the [mistakes](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistakes) tag, which seems more descriptive for this issue. However, I think we can find a better tag for that, too, and I'd like to see a suggestion in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should remove the tag.  Here are the questions currently tagged this way and proposed tagging changes.

[I am being blamed for an incorrect moderator action I didn't take. What should be done?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/452/i-am-being-blamed-for-an-incorrect-moderator-action-i-didnt-take-what-should-b) (also bears the problematic "moderator-relationship" tag, which I'm ignoring for now): this is about [conflict-resolution](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-resolution), and maybe [user-behavior](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior).

[How should I deal with a moderator who shows favoritism?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/360/how-should-i-deal-with-a-moderator-who-shows-favoritism): already tagged [bias](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias), which is sufficient.

[How can a site be rescued after an exodus of moderators?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122/how-can-a-site-be-rescued-after-an-exodus-of-moderators): I see we have a [backlash](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlash) tag (which I'm uncertain about, but if we have it, it seems to apply).  This is also about [community-building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-building).

[Moderator bans user in the course of an on-topic argument](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30/moderator-bans-user-in-the-course-of-an-on-topic-argument): [conflict-resolution](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-resolution) and [user-behavior](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior) seem to cover this fine.  (I have an edit pending here, actually, made before I thought about the larger problem with this tag.)

[How do you handle community backlash over an incorrect action taken by a moderator?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-do-you-handle-community-backlash-over-an-incorrect-action-taken-by-a-moderat): already tagged [backlash](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlash) and [mistakes](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistakes); that seems sufficient.  Also, as described, this question isn't so much about *bad* moderation as *erroneous* moderation; while errors are bad, "bad" here seems to be more about intent/malice.

[How should we deal with moderators who are making bad calls?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-should-we-deal-with-moderators-who-are-making-bad-calls): sounds like [conflict-resolution](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-resolution) to me.  And if we don't already have a tag for moderator oversight (covering, e.g., issues involving site owners and other people above the moderators), maybe we need one.